# Select attribute from a layer

Tags: qgis, layers, select, html

I'm trying to show an array of selected field values in HTML in the map composer.

So far, this works but only for a specific `value1` :

`[% array_to_string( array( attribute(get_feature('layer', 'attribute1', value1), 'attribute2')))%]`

What I want is to collect all the attribute from multiple selected features. I tried using `is_selected()` without success so far.