# QGIS Forms Filter - A distance filter expression to select features of a layer from current geometry

Tags: qgis, buffer, forms

So, I have a layer with an attribute `contact`, and I want to join these features with feature of the current geometry - so it selects all whose distance is less than 150.
I currently have a list of all the features in QGIS drop down forms that shows list of all contacts, but I want to filter it to a specific radius.

1. It's like creating a buffer from a current geometry (say point) and select all the features of another layer inside it.
2. Or maybe we can use some distance formula with array aggregate to select all the features whose DISTANCE from current geometry is less than 150.

ALthough it seems easy, I still have used lot of my hours on it, and it seems my brain is stuck. So a fresh perspective could provide a real help.

[image: Attribute Form View]

Below is the form view, without filter. I want a filter that select features in 150m radius of current point geometry.

[image: Form View]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will completely resolve your problem but in my case, I tried to show lines features from a layer that are below a certain distance value from a one specific polygon from another layer :

```
distance (
   closest_point (
      segments_to_lines (
         geometry (
            get_feature_by_id ('field',  @id_field>)
         )
      ),
      $geometry
   ), 
   $geometry
) < 150
```

If I understand correctly your expression, you don't set a distance limit.

Comment: Yeah, that as an expression works - but I want a filter that select **values** whose distance from current feature is WITHIN 150m. I have this expression `array_foreach(aggregate('Sales', 'array_agg', $geometry), distance(@element, $geometry))` returns distance of all geometries. But I want **values** - not distances. In another way, first I selects all features of an attribute of 'Sales' layer. And then on this array use **array_filter** function to filter it by distance. I'm able to get the distance, but not the contacts. So, that's why cannot filter it.

Comment: [Maybe like this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362915/select-attribute-from-a-layer).. It's your question btw (SPOOKY COINCIDENCE).